# Finding rotation quaternion from orthonormal basis?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, quaternion

Given three 3D unit vectors \$a\$, \$b\$, \$c\$ such that:

\$a \times b = c\$

\$b \times c = a\$

\$c \times a = b\$

(ie \$a, b, c\$ form an *orthonormal basis*)

How do we calculate a unit quarternion \$q\$ such that the sandwidch product (ie rotation) of \$q\$ on (1,0,0) is \$a\$, (0,1,0) is \$b\$ and (0,0,1) is \$c\$ ?

Comment: This operation (usually using only vectors a & b, since as you point out these two fully specify c already) is often called "LookRotation" and [you can find implementations of it with a quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=quaternion+lookrotation+implementation). Have you had any specific difficulty putting the examples you've found into practice?

Answer (score 3):

@Andrew Tomazos is correct, but conversion of the three vectors to a matrix first requires the storage of 16x additional floats, and is a bit slow.

A better solution is found by writing out the basis vectors a,b,c and plugging these into the matrix-to-quaternion conversion, where the elements are explicit.

```
m[0][0] = a.x, m[1][0] = b.x, m[2][0] = c.x
m[0][1] = a.y, m[1][1] = b.y, m[2][1] = c.y
m[0][2] = a.z, m[1][2] = b.z, m[2][2] = c.z
```

Now, we rewrite the matrix-to-quaternion function using the subsituted orthonormal vectors a,b,c. The result is the following function:

```
// Quaternion from orthogonal basis
Quaternion& Quaternion::fromBasis(Vector3DF a, Vector3DF b, Vector3DF c)
{
    float T = a.x + b.y + c.z;
    float s;
    if (T > 0) {
        float s = sqrt(T + 1) * 2.f;
        X = (c.y - b.z) / s;
        Y = (a.z - c.x) / s;
        Z = (b.x - a.y) / s;
        W = 0.25f * s;
    } else if ( a.x > b.y && a.x > c.z) {
        s = sqrt(1 + a.x - b.y - c.z) * 2;
        X = 0.25f * s;
        Y = (b.x + a.y) / s;
        Z = (a.z + c.x) / s;
        W = (c.y - b.z) / s;
    } else if (b.y > c.z) {
        s = sqrt(1 + b.y - a.x - c.z) * 2;
        X = (b.x + a.y) / s;
        Y = 0.25f * s;
        Z = (c.y + b.z) / s;
        W = (b.z - c.y) / s;
    } else {
        s = sqrt(1 + c.z - a.x - b.y) * 2;
        X = (a.z + c.x) / s;
        Y = (c.y + b.z) / s;
        Z = 0.25f * s;
        W = (b.x - a.y) / s;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This function gives a quaternion (X,Y,Z,W) directly from the orthonormal basis vectors a,b,c without intermediate storage of a matrix. You may still need to normalize the quaternion. If you have a direction and up-vector, say for a camera, you can construct the basis as: a=dir, b=up, c=cross(dir,up)

Answer (score 1):

An orthonormal basis forms a rotation matrix trivially by combining the three vectors and transposing (recall for an orthonormal matrix the inverse is just the transpose).  The resulting rotation matrix can then be converted into a quarternion in the usual fashion.